# Is there a way to pipe stdout/stdin across a command?

Tags: ssh, stream, pipe, webcam, vlc

Or more specifically is there a way to take stdout from one command, run another command, and then use stdout as the stdin for the next command?
e.g.
cat file.txt| run_command | grep "foo"

This may seem confusing as to why someone would want to do this. Here is what I am trying to do:

I feed the webcam on my other computer (remote) to my local computer via
ssh user@remote ffmpeg -b 100k -an -f video4linux2 -s 320x280 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 -b 100k -f ogg - | vlc -

I am trying to do the reverse. So, send a feed from my webcam (local) to display on the remote machine.
It tryed:
ffmpeg -b 100k -an -f video4linux2 -s 320x280 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 -b 100k -f ogg - | ssh user@remote vlc -

which doesn't work because before I have to "export DISPLAY=:0.0" on the remote machine before I can launch vlc. So I'm trying to get the output from ffmpeg to vlc on the remote computer AFTER exporting the DISPLAY variable for that ssh 'session'. 
Also if there is another way to do this (besides using ssh on the remote maching to use the first command) I would love to try it.(also if there is a way to do the same thing that doesn't lag so much I would appreciate the info, though that's not really relevant to the question) Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: You could try wrapping the call to `vlc` in a script that sets up `$DISPLAY`, although you may need more than `$DISPLAY` set up to connect to the X server these days.

Comment: Can you try `ffmpeg -b 100k -an -f video4linux2 -s 320x280 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 -b 100k -f ogg - | ssh user@remote "DISPLAY=:0.0 vlc -"` and see if it works? May need to use xauth or other things before we get a definitive answer, but try this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass the output from `source` as an input to `sink` given that `run_command` must end before `sink` is run in your case:

```
source | { run_command &>/dev/null; sink; }
```

Comment: I tried this and similar variations but I couldn't get it to work going through ssh.

Comment: Nevermind I just got it with:
ffmpeg -b 100k -an -f video4linux2 -s 320x280 -r 10 -i /dev/video0 -b 100k -f ogg - | ssh user@remote "{ export DISPLAY=:0.0 &>/dev/null; vlc - ; }"

Comment: for `ssh` command, you can use [@Mark Plotnick's command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509855/is-there-a-way-to-pipe-stdout-stdin-across-a-command/20510260?noredirect=1#comment30661014_20509855). There is no need to use `{}` syntax and the redirection in this case.

Comment: I know. I marked this one as the answer since it was posted as an answer and was also a valid answer. I am using Mark Plotnic's command, but I felt this one may have answered my initial question better, and be a little more generic.